# NumPy changes the value when slicing

Tags: python, numpy

I am using simple formula

```
beta = covariance[0,1]/covariance[1,1]
```

where covariance is

```
[[  1.96330748e-05   2.39329295e-05]
 [  2.39329295e-05   1.05846999e-04]]
```

when I print

```
covariance[1,1]
```

NumPy returns 0.000105846998912 instead of 1.05846999e-04, changing the value of original item in array, and i am experiencing this problem only when I run this covariance[1,1] statement in my terminal. If I run the same stuff in Jupiter it works just fine. Can you help me?

Comment: The two are the same. The only difference is *how* numpy and Python repesent floating points.

Comment: yes, but why when i do covariance[0,1] I am getting 2.39329295e-05 and can not get 1.05846999e-04 with covariance[1,1]?

Comment: Because Python will use scientific notation when the value is less than 1e-4. It is rather ugly to write 0.000000000011231211414.

Comment: You probably did not get the question, Jupiter gets me the correct answer and Python in terminal is not, when i perform calculations i need to do apples with apples, can you get me a solution?

Comment: Because I am getting the wrong answer for Beta beta = covariance[0,1]/covariance[1,1]

Comment: both are floating points. It is only the Python interpreter that uses a slighly different **representation** of floats than Jupyter.

Comment: I got that, but the answer in formula is affected by that representation

Comment: If the problem is that you get different results, you might want to make a simple reproducible example where you show how to get different results. The above example does not allow me to paste the code and confirm your "wrong" answer.

Comment: @ArtYudin is it affected? How do you know? What are the different results you are getting?

Comment: Jupiter returns 1.219811444283643 vs 0.2261087209244577

Comment: So how do I perform calculations between scientific and floats, although covariance.dtype returns floats64

Comment: "scientific" is not a data type. It is simply the *way a float is being printed to the screen*. This is almost *certainly* not the source of the discrepancy. Again, it would be great if you could provide a reproducible example, or, at least an example of your jupyter output vs your terminal output.

Comment: @ArtYudin Also, are you sure you aren't doing `covariance[1,0] / covariance[0,0]` accidentally? That would explain the result of `1.219811444283643`

Answer (score 2):

`0.000105846998912` is equal to `1.05846999e-04`.

One is scientific notation and the other isn't.

Comment: yes, but why when i do covariance[0,1] I am getting 2.39329295e-05   and can not get 1.05846999e-04 with covariance[1,1]?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the "floating point" are wrong questions relate to the difference between the formatting and internal representation of a floating point. The computer can't represent the "formatted" floating point exactly.

Things to be aware of are what kind of floating point am I using, for example here you could check if you are using a [float32](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html) or `float64` type array. You can check this by typing:

```
covariance.dtype
```

You can set the details of how values are printed using the `set_printoptions` [function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) from numpy. Also make sure you are aware of how floating point values are [printed](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#floating-point-arithmetic-issues-and-limitations), in different python versions.

This is what you would call a "reproducible" example:

```
import numpy as np
covariance = np.array(
    [
        [1.96330748e-05, 2.39329295e-05],
        [2.39329295e-05, 1.05846999e-04]
    ],
    dtype="double"
)
print(covariance[1, 1])
print(repr(covariance[1, 1]))
print("{:.20f}".format(covariance[1, 1]))

beta = covariance[0, 1] / covariance[1, 1]
print("{:.20f}".format(beta))

# this generates the "wrong" answer you mention in the comments under your answer.
wrong_beta = covariance[0, 1] / covariance[0, 0]
print("{:.20f}".format(wrong_beta))
```

If I run it under jupyter with python3.5 I get:

```
0.000105846999
0.000105846999
0.00010584699900000000
0.22610872038044271815
1.21901076340828695699
```

If I run it under python console I get the same answer.

Comment: Checked, float64, problem not with printing, problem with the formula where the same array yields different results with the same syntax beta = covariance[0,1]/covariance[1,1]